# counting survey data responses by entry for multiple entries

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to have excel quickly count the number of each responses in a survey as shown in the snapshot? I need to know how many strongly agree, agree, neutral, etc responses there are for each of the 30 or so questions.

Snapshot of data tables I am working with:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to count Agree for example or Sum the numbers next to it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for pivot table for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the count near the Column of Agree... you can use:

`=IF(E2=E1,"",COUNTIF($E$2:$E$23,E2))`

Start your Data in Row2 and leave E1 empty (the whole row 1)
E2:E23 is the answers (Agree, Strongly agree...) change it to correspond to the Data you need to count
The $ to keep the references fix so you can drag the formula down
If your Data is Sorted like the screenshot countif will count once per answer
If E3 is different from E2 for example it will count and write the answer in front of the first row
If E3 = E2 it will give empty ""

Another Way if your Data is not sorted
Copy the column of each question (Agree...) and paste in another place Column G, Remove Duplicates and next to it write:
`=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$23,G2)`

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is counting responses to particular questions, the use `COUNTIFS`

`=COUNTIFS(Table1[Question], B15, Table1[Response], C15)`

[image: COUNTIFS survey response table]

You can put the summary table anywhere, including other sheet. Just be sure to change B15 and C15 to the corresponding cell where you want the specific pair of question and answer.